# url mapping params to lowercase

Tags: grails

Here is a part of `UrlMapping.groovy` I'm using `grails 2.2.2`

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}

"/$username/private"(controller: 'contributor', action: 'indexPrivate')
```

When `$username` is "SteevMacQueen" url is /**SteevMacQueen**/private

I want it in lowercase /**steevmacqueen**/private

How can I achieve that ?

Thank you

Comment: did you simply try `"/$username?.toLowerCase/private"(controller: 'contributor', action: 'indexPrivate')`

Comment: I actually did try `/$username?.toLowerCase()/private"...` :( thanks for the answer but I have resolved the problem another way.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Would be nice if you answer your own question to help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find any way to do it via `UrlMapping.groovy` so I have created a filter
where I set the username to lowercase

```
def username = { attrs, body ->
    out << User.findById(springSecurityService.principal.id).username.toLowerCase()
}
```

then in the view I use this filter

```
href="/<mc:username/>/private"
```

Not very sexy but problem is resolved